The context menu is not showing when using EditableText widget in Flutter
The context menu is not showing when using an EditableText widget in flutter. Here is an example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen()));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 40,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: 1),
                ),
              ),
              EditableText(
                controller: controller,
                focusNode: focusNode,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19),
                cursorColor: Colors.black,
                backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black,
                selectionControls: materialTextSelectionControls,
                contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
                  print('================ Triggered ==================');
                  return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
                    anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
                    buttonItems: editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems,
                  );
                },
                enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                selectionColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.3),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

In this example, when the text in the EditableText widget is highlighted, the context menu does not show up.
I am using flutter version 3.10.5. I have tried running the app on an physical android device and on an android virtual device but the same issue occurs.
Please, help.

By default, the context menu does not open on highlight. TextField opens it manually in the onSelectionChanged. This is a way to do it in EditableText:
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen()));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  final GlobalKey<EditableTextState> editableTextKey =
      GlobalKey<EditableTextState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 250, 20, 0),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6, vertical: 6),
        width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(),
        ),
        child: EditableText(
          key: editableTextKey,
          controller: controller,
          focusNode: focusNode,
          showSelectionHandles: true,
          onSelectionChanged:
              (TextSelection selection, SelectionChangedCause? cause) {
            EditableTextState? editableText = editableTextKey.currentState;

            if (cause == SelectionChangedCause.longPress) {
              editableText?.bringIntoView(selection.extent);
              editableText?.showToolbar();
            }
          },
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19),
          cursorColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black,
          selectionControls: Platform.isIOS
              ? cupertinoTextSelectionControls
              : materialTextSelectionControls,
          enableInteractiveSelection: true,
          selectionColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.3),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

It is still better to use TextField because it has handles semantics, platform specifics, and has more features but for this works for my application.
Thank you for your help.
